# list of pages and categories

Tags: wordpress

I've a question.
My wordpress theme, prints a list of pages in `<ul>` tag.
My pages name:

> page1, page2, page3

OK ... Now can I prints my categories names inside the pages list? for example:

```
<ul><li>page1</li><li>page2</li><li>category1<li><li>page3</li></ul>
```

If I can, how I can?

Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you user Wordpress 3.0, use the Custom Menu under Appereance -> Menus.

It let you build a menu with pages, categories, links !